# Lead status visibility

Tags: leads

Currently Lead status have 5 options for the picklist ( qualified, unqualified, converted, disqualified, junk)

How to make the specific users or page layout can see only 3 options for the picklist (qualified, disqualified, junk), the other 2 are just hidden or not visible?

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: you can either remove those values or deactivate them (but it applies for everyone)

Comment: You can do this with record types, but the available values will depend on the record's type, not the user editing the record or the layout assigned to it. You can't specifically assign specific values to specific profiles, although you could use validation rules to prevent users from using values they shouldn't be able to save.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different record type for this purpose. Configure Lead Status picklist values for each record type. Use different page layouts for different record type. You can associate several record types with a profile.

Refer:-

[Create record type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_record_types.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=208.9)

[Edit picklist values for record type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=editing_picklists_for_record_types_and_business_processes.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=208.9)

[Assign record type for profiles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_recordtype.htm&type=0)